# Clickable area around linestring in mapbox GL js

Tags: javascript, popup, mapbox-gl-js, multilinestring

I'm using mapbox GL js to display linestrings.

Those linestrings are clickable in order to display various information about the linstring in a popup using :

```
      new mapboxgl.Popup()
          .setLngLat(coordinates)
          .setHTML(popup)
          .addTo(map);
```

But I have the feeling that the clickable area where the popup is displayed is very narrow. It can even manage to display the popup everytime on the first clic...

Is there a way to enlarge this zone ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common work around I use is to create a second `line` layer underneath, with a `line-opacity` of 0.01 and a `line-width` of 10. Add the click handler onto that line instead.